# What are roles in ER diagrams used for?

Tags: entity-relationship

The book for the database course I'm following, displays the following image to illustrate how roles work in ER diagrams:

[image: 'Prereq' stands for a prerequisite that the course has; another course that should be followed before the course can be followed.]

However, this doesn't really make clear to me what exactly they're used for. Why is course_id displayed as a role when it's already an attribute of course, and why is prereq_id not a descriptive attribute of the relationship prereq?

If anyone could explain to me what roles are used for in ER modelling and answer my two questions, I'd be very grateful :)

Note: 'prereq' stands for a prerequisite that the course has; another course that should be followed before the course can be followed.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is not a great example of how role indicators should be used. They can improve readability of an ER diagram by providing more information about how each of the connected entities is associated with the relation.

In this example, I would have opted for something more like **requires** instead of **course_id** and **required by** instead of **prereq_id**. That way, it provides additional information about what the lines mean. In this example it doesn't make much of a difference, but in other situations these role indicators can be helpful to clarify somewhat what the semantics of a relation are, particularly when it's hard to specify that clearly with the name of the relation alone.

Edit: I found this example, which is somewhat different from how I explained it above, but a great example of how role indicators can be used:

[Role indicators example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDkfl.png)